# how do I reference the event argument in Dart web ui html event attributes?

Tags: dart

In JS/HTML it's common to have things like `<a onclick="func(event)">`, how do I reference the event variable when I'm using dart? I get an error when I try to do this saying that event is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more complete example:

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" on-change="itChanged($event)">
```

In the Dart file:

```dart
itChanged(Event event) {
  print(event.target.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some research it turns out you have to use $event.